# How to break/pause a loop for X time then start same loop again?

Tags: php, while-loop, break

I have a php `while` loop that sends three random numbers from 5 in 5 seconds each number with `sleep(5)` function.

What I want is that when the first loop finishes, I want to break it for 60 seconds then start same loop again.

```
$i= 1
do{
    $one = mt_rand(1, 99);
    $two = mt_rand(1, 99);
    $three = mt_rand(1, 99);
    $this->SendMessage( 'Number: '.$one.'' );
    sleep(5);
    $this->sendMessage( 'Number: '.$two.'' );
    sleep(5);
    $this->sendMessage( 'Number: '.$three.'' );
    sleep(5);
    $this->SendMessage( 'The three random numbers has been send, another three numbers will be show in 60 seconds.' );
    $i++;
}
while ($i<100);
```

And here I want to pause the loop for 60 seconds, I don't want to use sleep function to pause; I want to use something like break that stops the loop and after 60 seconds starts it again.

I have using cli task to start the code.

Comment: How did you start your code? Its cli task or from browser?

Comment: I start the code in Task

Comment: What the reason, that you don't want to use `sleep`?

Comment: Because i want to make some updates and if is in sleep php cant do nothing in this time..

Answer (score 0):

I guess it might become possible using [PHP threads](http://docs.php.net/Thread). See the PHP manual, examples, etc. If i wrong, you also may look up how to do async functions calls